# Call to undefined method Facebook::setUser()

Tags: php, facebook

Anyone know if there is a new way in the new API to set the user? I'm getting the error, `Call to undefined method Facebook::setUser()`. I cant find anything on Google.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to paste the error.

Comment: @Adam Backstrom: It's in the title. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the "call to undefined method" error because the class doesn't contain a `setUser()` method.

This method has been replaced by the new `getSession` method, which attempts to parse user data from the `fbs_*` cookie (for Facebook Connect implementations) or HTTP GET parameters (for Facebook Canvas applications).